# HttpURLConnection irregular SocketException

Tags: java, timeout, httpurlconnection, socketexception

I made a java program for downloading some images from a selectable directory from any website.
Everything is working fine, but sometimes it doesn't continue downloading but throws a SocketException after a while. Here the error log:

```
...
62.png downloaded
63.png downloaded
64.png downloaded
65.png downloaded
66.png downloaded
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at DownloadImage.main(DownloadImage.java:35)
```

The files are not the problem. Sometimes it stops at the 5th image, sometimes at the 70th. It seems to be pretty random.

I suspect an uneven connection to the url I try to reach. But how can I fix it? I tried to set the connect and the read timeouts to a hilarious value

```
huc.setConnectTimeout(3600000);
huc.setReadTimeout(3600000);
```

but it didn't solve it.

Any ideas? Or does my problem have another root?

Comment: You can't fix a problem at the server end from your end. Setting a read timeout is always a good idea, but this value is just silly, and won't affect this problem. Setting the connection timeout to a huge value is pointless as (a) you can't increase it beyond the platform default of about a minute, and (b) it has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Ok, I thought the timeout would make my client wait longer for an answer of the server. Well then I have to think of another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your source code? Maybe you don't check for errors the right way. (Errors happen...)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for my problem now.

The SocketException is thrown by

```
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(websiteUrl.openStream());
```

so I built a try'n'catch clause and a while loop around it:

```
ReadableByteChannel rbc = null;
while (true) {
    try {
        rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        break;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("connection failed");
    }
}
```

It doesn't solve the bad connection problems of course, but at least I can download everything in a single run of my program now.